# segmentation Fault (core dumped) fread function

Tags: c, file

I want to read files in a directory, check if they are ELF type and print 10 first bytes of those files. The problem is in `fread(buffer,1,4,f1);` line. In first while loop iteration everything works fine, but at second iteration this error pops up :  "segmentation Fault (core dumped)". Does anybody know why does this error appears in this case? I know there are lots of questions related to this problem but i can't find the answer

```
while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir))!= NULL){
       void *dl;
       dl = dlopen( pDirent->d_name, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL );  

       if(dl != NULL){
          printf("Failo vardas %s tai yra dinamine biblioteka \n",pDirent->d_name);

       }else{
          char buffer[4];
          FILE *f1;
          f1 = fopen(pDirent->d_name, "r" );                       
          fread(buffer,1,4,f1);
          if(buffer[0] == 0x7f && buffer[1] == 'E' && buffer[2] == 'L' && buffer[3] =='F'){
             printf("%s sis failas nera dinamine biblioteka, tai yra ELF failas \n",pDirent->d_name);             
          }
          fclose(f1);
          FILE *f2;
          f2 = fopen(pDirent->d_name, "r" );
          char buf[10];
          fread(buf,1,10,f2);
          printf("%s file 10 baitu : %s \n",pDirent->d_name,buf);
          fclose(f2);
       }
       dlclose( dl );
```

}

Comment: Check the return value of `fopen` and of fread`.

Comment: Where is pDir coming from? If you're looking at any directory except for the current one, you'll need to prepend the directory name (and slash) to the filename to be able to open it.

Comment: I had to check if f1 and f2 was not NULL and error disappeared

Answer (score 5):

`buf` is not null-terminated, so printing it with `%s` is an undefined behavior.

Comment: This seems true but unlikely to be related, as `printf()` should just print garbage until it does find a zero.

Comment: The behavior is undefined, which means that we cannot assume that `printf()` *shoud* do anything at all.

Comment: OK, so to answer the OP question, why is a seg fault happening?  Are you saying "maybe it's the printf()"?